# can't install libsdl1.2-dev on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to install these libraries on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev
```

But it only shows this error:

```
libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going
                    to be installed or libglu-dev
                Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

I've tried:

```
1. aptitude install
2. apt-get install -f
```

and I can't find other solutions other than these.

How can I solve this problem..? Help me please!

Comment: Try: sudo apt-get install libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev its working for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another thing you can try is to do:

```
sudo apt install libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev
```